# CloudKit Subscription Not Firing for Record Creation only for Update

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3, cloudkit, subscriptions

I am trying to keep multiple devices in synch using CloudKit.  Specifically, I am trying to keep attributes of action figures (action figure specifics) consistent based on what is stored in iCloud/CloudKit.  I am using the subscriptions to notify when a record has changed.  The update record fires and is received just fine.  If I split the subscription into two separate subscriptions - 1 for create and 1 for update, neither fires.

```
let actionFigureRefernece = CKReference(recordID: actionFigureRecordId, action: .deleteSelf)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"actionFigureReference == %@", actionFigureRefernece)
```

Table layout of figure reference and specifics attributes:

```
 actionFigureReference Reference
 haveFigureCount Int(64)
 haveTheFigure Int(64)
```

Here is the code.

```
func saveActionFigureSpecifics() {

    // set and save core data
    actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate = NSDate()
    SharedData.sharedInstance.appDelegate.saveContext()

    // save to iCloud based on user preference
    if SharedData.sharedInstance.isUserPreferenceToUseICloud == true {
        // Private Database
        let privateDatabase = SharedData.sharedInstance.privateDatabase

        // record IDs
        let actionFigureRecordId = CKRecordID(recordName: actionFigureGlobalUniqueId)
        let actionFigureSpecificRecordId = CKRecordID(recordName: actionFigureSpecificsGlobalUniqueId)

        // Initialize Reference
        if actionFigureSpecificsRecord == nil {
            // set the record type
            actionFigureSpecificsRecord = CKRecord(recordType: kActionFigureSpecificsRecord, recordID: actionFigureSpecificRecordId)

            // set the record details
            let actionFigureReference = CKReference(recordID: actionFigureRecordId, action: .deleteSelf)
            actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(actionFigureReference, forKey: kActionFigureReference)
        }

        // iCloud attributes
        actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveTheFigure as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kHaveTheFigure)
        actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveFigureCount as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kHaveFigureCount)
        actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantTheFigure as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kWantTheFigure)
        actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kUpdateDate)

        // Create subscription
        // push notification
        self.saveActionFigureSpecificsICloudSubscriptions(withReference: actionFigureRecordId) {
            results, error in

            if let error = error {
                print("Error saving subscription: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            // Save Record
            privateDatabase!.save(self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!) { (actionFigureRecord, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        #if DEBUG
                            print("WARNING: Error saving specifics of \(actionFigureRecordId.recordName) \(error!)")
                        #endif

                        self.isActionFigureSpecificSetFromICloud = false
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // set the record to the saved record.
                        self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord = actionFigureRecord!

                        let actionFigureReference = actionFigureRecord!.object(forKey: kActionFigureReference) as! CKReference
                        let actionFigureRecoreId = actionFigureReference.recordID
                        #if DEBUG
                            print("Save executed and successful on \(kActionFigureSpecificsRecord) for \(actionFigureRecoreId.recordName)")
                        #endif
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Subscription Addition

```
func saveActionFigureSpecificsICloudSubscriptions(withReference actionFigureRecordId: CKRecordID, completion : @escaping (_ results: CKSubscription?, _ error : Error?) -> Void) {
    let privateDatabase = SharedData.sharedInstance.privateDatabase

    let subscriptionId = "\(actionFigureRecordId.recordName)_\(kActionFigureSpecificsRecord)_Subscription"

    // get subscriptions
    privateDatabase?.fetchAllSubscriptions(completionHandler: { (subscriptions, error) in

        if let err = error {
            #if DEBUG
                print("Fetch subscription failed \(err.localizedDescription)")
            #endif

            completion(nil, err)

            return

        } else {
            var isSubscriptionCreated: Bool = false

            for subscription in subscriptions! {
                //if subscriptionId == subscription.subscriptionID {
                if subscription.subscriptionID.contains(subscriptionId) {
                    #if DEBUG
                        print("subscription detail exists for \(subscription.subscriptionID)")
                    #endif

                    isSubscriptionCreated = true
                }

            }

            // if the subscription doesn't exist, create the subscription
            if isSubscriptionCreated == false {
                let actionFigureRefernece = CKReference(recordID: actionFigureRecordId, action: .deleteSelf)
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"actionFigureReference = %@", actionFigureRefernece)
                //let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

                let subscriptionIdInsert = "\(subscriptionId)"
                let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: kActionFigureSpecificsRecord, predicate: predicate, subscriptionID: subscriptionIdInsert, options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate])

                let notification = CKNotificationInfo()

                var actionFigure: ActionFigure?

                if let specificsDelegate = self.delegate as? ActionFigure {
                    actionFigure = specificsDelegate
                    notification.alertBody = "Action figure specifics \(actionFigure!.series) \(actionFigure!.actionFigureName) updated"
                }
                else {
                    notification.alertBody = "Action figure specifics updated"
                }

                notification.shouldBadge = true
                notification.soundName = "default"

                subscription.notificationInfo = notification

                privateDatabase?.save(subscription, completionHandler: ({returnRecord, error in
                    if let err = error {
                        #if DEBUG
                            print("subscription creation failed \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        #endif

                        completion(nil, err)

                        return

                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            #if DEBUG
                                print("Success:  Subscription set up successfully for specifics on \(subscriptionId)")
                            #endif

                            completion(returnRecord, nil)

                            return
                        }
                    }
                }))
            }
            else {  // subscription exists
                completion(nil, nil)
                return
            }
        }
    })
}
```

AppDelegate Functions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SharedDataToyLine.sharedInstance.setToyLines()


    // Register to receive notification
    //create the notificationCenter
    let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert]) { (granted, error) in
        // nothing to do yet
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // Google adds
    FIRApp.configure()
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: kGADMobileAdsMobileAppId)

    // Amazon adds
    AmazonAdRegistration.shared().setAppKey(kAmazonMyToyChestAPIKey)

    return true
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

    let notification: CKNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String : NSObject])

    if (notification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.query) {
        let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification
        let recordId: CKRecordID = queryNotification.recordID!
        #if DEBUG
            print("Foreground push for record name returned from push \(recordId.recordName)")
        #endif

        if let shareDataActionFigureArrayIndex = SharedDataActionFigure.sharedInstance.getIndexForActionFigure(byActionFigureSpecificsRecordId: recordId) {
            #if DEBUG
                print("Record index for push \(recordId.recordName) is \(shareDataActionFigureArrayIndex)")
            #endif

            SharedDataActionFigure.sharedInstance.actionFigureArray[shareDataActionFigureArrayIndex].actionFigureSpecifics.setActionFigureSpecificsFromPushNotification()
        }
    }
}
```

Subscription

```
RecordType
    ActionFigureSpecifics
Trigger
    UPDATE<br>INSERT
Criteria
    ActionFigureSpecifics.actionFigureReference (equals reference)
```

Comment: Jack, the records contain metadata about their contents, try looking into using that to determine if the update your getting is a duplicate.

Comment: Updated the code with corrections to save the subscription first and then the record.  Also confirmed that metadata in the record contents is needed.  Added in the CKReference to the predicate.  Now I am getting unique update subscriptions by CKReference predicate, but no record insert/creates are firing the subscription.

Comment: Jack, a while back; maybe it's better now I found the subscription engine unreliable when running buggy code against it. If you subscribe to the same database again and again it simply breaks. The only fix was to reset the environment. If you're convinced it is correct and it makes no sense it doesn't work.. or indeed if you make no changes to the area now misbehaving maybe its got confused. reset.

Comment: On a different but related note by metadata, I was referring to code like this snip bit when talking about metadata. query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)] which is the data about data, the time of creation in this case. I am not sure you can rely on CloudKit subscriptions to keep track of which devices it has sent what updates to reliably, if your find this to be the case than recode a different solution. Try using coredata for example.